# how to automate user actions on a page in react native app

Tags: javascript, react-native

i made an app that opens a page in in app browser, now my task is to make it to click on a link and on the page and get a content of the table, is there any library that I could use to complete the task? I am curious if there are libraries to inject javascript code into a page in in app browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the functions of a InApp browser
[react-native-inappbrowser-reborn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-inappbrowser-reborn)

If there'snt a function which serves your needs, you can create a fork of the [library](https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser) itself and make it your own!